# Rescale vector without mean, sd, min and max

Tags: r, scale, distribution, rescale

I have an asymetrical distribution :

```
x <- c(rnorm(100, 0, 1),
     rnorm(100, 2.5, 0.5))
```

[image]

I would like to shift it so the old "0" value is now 100 and the old "2" value is now "15". However, I would like to do it without using old nor new min/max values.

Using the `scale` function is not appropriated as it shifts the mean to an new value, and I'd like to shift a specific value to a new one. I can't make `rescale` do it neither.

```
  plot(density(scale(x)*15+100))
  plot(density(scales::rescale(x, from=c(0, 2), to=c(100, 15))))
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works with rescale:

`scales::rescale(x, from=c(0, 2), to=c(100, 100+15))`